# Error obtaining UI hierarchy Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file: com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist

Tags: android, xml, testing, adb, android-uiautomator

I am testing my app with adb, but i get this error when i execute "dump view hierarchy for uiautomator":

> Error obtaining UI hierarchy Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML
>   file: com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist!

My adb version is 1.0.36 and my android version is 6.0.1.

This error comes launched only when in the interface there is a dynamic element that is in motion.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 33):

The best way is to kill the adb server and start it again.

- sudo adb kill-server
- sudo adb start-server

This will do the trick.

Comment: The commands worked for me, but I didn't need the `sudo` bit.

Comment: Don't forget to restart UIAutomator Viewer.

Answer (score 18):

Currently your UI needs to be idle (as in no [Accessibility Events](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html) sent) for at least 1000ms before the [AccessibilityService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html) will be able to produce the UI hierarchy dump.

If you would try to run `adb shell uiautomator dump` it would give you the `ERROR: could not get idle state.`

Comment: if i wanted to test an app not made by me but with the same problem?
thank you in advance.

Comment: it's a limitation of the AccessibilityService itself.  I am guessing that an app changing its UI more frequently than once per second is not considered *accessible*

Comment: therefore doesn't exist solution at this issue if i use adb?
Thank you again.

Answer (score 11):

Even though it's late I'm giving my observation here. Even I got this issue. Before taking the screen shot from UI Automator terminate the appium server connection. Then try to capture screenshot. It works fine.

Comment: That is correct, I have tried to restart my phone for several times, and It finally works

Answer (score 9):

I realise this is an old post. But I've noticed the same issue when I've use uiautomator to control the simulator for automation testing. It seems that the uiautomatorviewer does not connect to the emulator to take a screenshot after the emulator has been controlled by the uiautomator.

I found that running `adb reconnect` allows the uiautomatorviewer to take screenshots again.

Answer (score 8):

Try Restarting your device, which worked in my case.

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting this error

[image]

This means your UI Automator is got disconnected, to regain the connection, you can open the new terminal no need to worry about the location on the terminal.

Type the command

```
adb reconnect
```

and try again to take a screenshot it should work.

Answer (score 3):

in the device or emulator :

1. display the applications opened , and close them one by one.
2. refresh monitor.

   It should now be able to and get the hierarchies, as if one of the apps opened was "obfuscating" the parsing.

Answer (score 3):

The below command executed from command line worked for me;

```
adb shell am force-stop com.android.ddmlib
```

Answer (score 2):

Close other AccessibilityService in your phone please.

Answer (score 1):

Rebooting the device worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For those people who encountered this issue due to changes to the Accessibility Events faster than once a second.

```
ERROR: could not get idle state.
```

I found a comment on AndroidViewClient which is based on uiautomator where the author says that CulebraTester2-public exposes this functionality.

https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/issues/189#issuecomment-570775719

> https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public is not affected by
> this problem.
>
> It can be used to dump the hierarchy and also as an AndroidViewClient
> backend.

https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public
https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-client

I ran a simple test and it seems to work in my case.

Comment: glad to hear it works in your case. A simple test that can be run in that situations, to verify the difference, is the one described at https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public#androidviewclient; including or excluding `--use-uiautomator-helper` should show a successful dump or the error. Another advantage is that the dump could be in json.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the above steps and none of them did not work. The reason being I have tried to run the uiautomatorviewer after opening the app using Appium. Whenever I manually open my app on the device and then run the uiautomatorviewer works perfectly well. Just sharing my experience. Thanks

Comment: try `adb reconnect`. I've had the same issue. once the app is controlled via adb, it locks to that source. `adb reconnect` unlocked it for uiautomatorviewer to gain control and take the screenshot.

Comment: Same. I've tried all but still facing the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

By enable the developer option and usb debugging , issue resolve for me

Answer (score -1):

Before taking the screen shot from "uiautomatorviewer" please terminate the appium server connection by using ctrl+C command. Then try to capture screenshot. It works fine.

Comment: Reads more like a mediocre comment, not like an answer to the question.

Comment: In my case Appium server is not even running and I am still getting this error