# Ubuntu uiautomatorviewer Error while parsing UI hierarchy XML file

Tags: android, ubuntu, emulation, uiautomatorviewer

I am making this question for future searchers that might be as newbie as me. And also because I have not enough reputation to add comments on other answers.

- The error mentioned still happened after trying the following
  approaches:

  1. Turn on USB DEBUGGING
  2. Enable view attribute inspection
  3. Select the debug app option and choose com.github.uiautomator

  [Error in using UIAutomatorviewer for testing Android app in Appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201743/error-in-using-uiautomatorviewer-for-testing-android-app-in-appium)

  [Error obtaining UI hierarchy Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file: com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214342/error-obtaining-ui-hierarchy-error-while-obtaining-ui-hierarchy-xml-file-com-an)

The problem was that the whereis uiautomatorviewer throwed this path
/usr/bin/uiautomatorviewer

**Solution**

The one that actually does the work is
/root/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the linux command

> whereis uiautomatorviewer

throwed this path /usr/bin/uiautomatorviewer

**Solution**

The one that actually does the work is /root/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer

Comment: how to do this. how to open this in ubuntu

Comment: Hi @SajidZeb, go to a terminal and type whereis (this command represent an app that must be installed in Ubuntu with apt-get install APP). Once you checked "whereis" is installed type "whereis uiautomatorviewer"

Answer (score 0):

Paste this in your terminal. It will open the correct Autmator

```
Android/Sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Follow the script mentioned in image