# UI Automator Viewer is unable to take screenshot

Tags: android, appium-android, uiautomatorviewer

I am using Windows 7 - 64 bit system, Android Studio 3.2.1 version. ADB Version - 1.0.40

I have created an emulator and trying to take a screenshot using UI Automator Viewer component of Android SDK.

However, I am getting the below error every time I have tried.

My appium server is stopped, as suggest in some SO suggestions.

1. Can anybody please help me resolve the issue?

**Emulator config -**

[image]

**Error -**

[image]

2. Some of the suggestions say to close adb.exe from Task Manager. Can anybody please explain why this is required? Though I tried this with no avail.
3. Is there any good alternative of UIAutomatorViwer and can you please refer me about the usage of that inspector tool for Android App Testing using Appium?

Comment: some good ways given in:<br>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201743/error-in-using-uiautomatorviewer-for-testing-android-app-in-appium/25243843#comment56961162_25243843   AND   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214342/error-obtaining-ui-hierarchy-error-while-obtaining-ui-hierarchy-xml-file-com-an

Answer (score 0):

You can use **APPIUM Desktop** instead of **UI Automator Viewer**

**Appium Desktop**

I am using APPIUM Desktop from quite a long time, so i have documented the steps from a beginner prespective ,Installation and how to use it  is mentioned in below URL

https://automationlab0000.wordpress.com/2018/12/31/appium-desktop-for-locating-elements/